# Is it possible to learn all skills in Glitch?

Tags: glitch-2011

Is it possible to learn all skills in Glitch?  I haven't seen anything definitive either way, but it looks like you can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is currently possible to learn every skill available, and many people have.  The only disadvantage to learning more skills is that there is a compounding 3% time penalty for every skill you learn above a certain limit.  The limit is determined by your current level of the [Better Learning](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Better_Learning) Skill.

The effect of this is that learning many 'fast' skills will make the longer skills later in the tree far more difficult to learn.  The current maximum penalty is over 4x the base learning time, so for skills that take days or weeks, this can be significant.

Thus, learning some skills you aren't interested now might penalize you in the future, should there be a long learning time skill that is introduced into the game later down the line.  The game developers have said that they have many skills planned for release in the near future.

One of these skills is thought to be [Unlearning](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Unlearning_I), which will allow you to 'forget' skills that you don't have any interest in retaining.  It would take a fraction of the time it takes to learn a skill in order to Unlearn it. The time taken to Unlearn a skill is not affected by the aforementioned penalty and the Unlearning skills themselves also do not add to the penalty.

The Skillifier is a tool I developed to track skill times and help you prioritize, if learning time is an interest/concern:

http://agent86ix.github.com/glitch

Comment: So if I don't care about the "difficulty" of learning a skill (which is just time, and I can do while I'm not logged in), there's not really any harm in going nuts on the skill tree?  Have the devs hinted that they might change things in the future that you won't be able to learn all skills?

Comment: In my opinion, there's no harm in going nuts on the skill tree.  They have not released any information that indicates that they will limit characters to a fixed number of skills in the future.

Comment: Good answer. Early on I pursued Block Making and Fuel Making... before I really knew what they were (they just sounded cool). I'm eagerly awaiting Unlearning, so I can dump them.